# What is the best way to track internal referrals with php?

Tags: php

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` seems to be full of holes.

Tracking through the url will not be possible for this particular application.

I have a 301 Redirect to take into account also.

I will check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, but what is a good second method to check what page on my site the user came from?

Is it as simple as setting up a session variable? I am looking for specific examples that will help augment `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not sufficient, you can keep track of each script as you visit it with a `$_SESSION` variable, or set cookies on each page.  I'd go with the session - you can track scripts on the backend that the browser may not know about and it'll work even if the user has cookies disabled.  You could even keep a whole array of executed scripts, adding on the latest as the execution path makes it's way through your scripts.  You'd be able to trace the path from arrival to current script.

Comment: So as the visitor comes to each script, I could add another item to the array to indicate they visited that script. I need to make a decision on where to send the visitor based on the last page/script they visited, so I suppose my logic could simply check the http_referer and then check the last item in my session array as well?

Comment: Exactly, or skip http_referer altogether.